# Docker Compose with Rails docker-compose up failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I try to develop an app by Rails on Docker using WSL2 on Windows.

After Gemfile was modified by the next command in container,

```
rails new . --force --database=postgresql --skip-bundle
```

I had to install bundle, so I exited container and used this command.

```
docker-compose up --build -d
```

Then error has occurred saying...

```
[+] Building 0.9s (2/3)
[+] Building 1.0s (3/3) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                               0.1s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 32B                                                                                0.1s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                  0.1s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                    0.0s
 => ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ruby:2.5                                                  0.8s
------
 > [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ruby:2.5:
------
failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = error getting credentials - err: exit status 1, out:
```

docker-compose.yml is like this.

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    volumes:
      - '.:/product-register'
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
```

Dockerfile is like this.

```
FROM ruby:2.5
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    libpq-dev \
    nodejs \
    postgresql-client \
    yarn

WORKDIR /product-register
COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock /product-register/
RUN bundle install
```

Before entering container and executing the next command in container,

```
rails new . --force --database=postgresql --skip-bundle
```

this command

```
docker-compose up -d
```

worked!!

What should I do???

Comment: You might find it easier to use a version manager like `rbenv`, without Docker, to run commands like `rails new` that actively modify your source code, and to run RSpec tests without needing a Docker indirection layer.  I wouldn't try to edit code inside the container directly.

Comment: "docker-compose up --build -d" command worked after a while.
I don't have any idea why it worked.
By the way, thank you for your quick response!!

Answer (score -1):

After a while, I executed the command,

```
docker-compose up --build -d
```

it worked!!

I don't know why?

Thank you for your cooperation.

I am glad if you comment the cause if you know.